# Can't send email with nodemailer and outlook

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, nodemailer

i try to send an email with nodemailer and outlook but after multi try and multiple forum i visited, i found nothing. 
I try all the solution i've seen but nothing work. can you help me please

this is my code :

```
{
 const path = require('path');
  var message=fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname+'../../../asset/templateMail/mail.html')).toString();
  message=message.replace('${user}', user.confirmation_code.toString());

  var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(

       {
       //service :"Outlook365",
         //pool:true,
      host: 'SMTP.office365.com',
      port: '587',
      secure:false,
      auth: { user: "it-factory-flex@outlook.fr", pass:  process.env.NODEMAILLERPASS },
      //secureConnection: false,
      //requireTLS:true,
      //tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }

    }

  );

  var mailOptions = {
    name:"FlexOffice",
    from: "it-factory-flex@outlook.com",
    to: user.email,
    subject: "FlexOffice: Code d'inscription",
    html: message
  }
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }


  });
}
```

all the commented part are my test
and i always got this:

```
Error: Connection timeout
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/romain/bred/flex-server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
at SMTPConnection._onError (/home/romain/bred/flex-server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20)
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/romain/bred/flex-server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, due to my network who block the flux.